# Obout Combobox events only fire on page load

Tags: asp.net, combobox, obout

I have the following obout control on my page:

```
<cc1:ComboBox ID="ActivityTypeComboBox" runat="server" Width="100" AllowEdit="False">
    <ClientSideEvents OnSelectedIndexChanged="alert('x')" OnItemClick="alert('y')" />
</cc1:ComboBox>
```

Both of the ClientSideEvents fire when the page first loads but not after that when I actually do the events.

Any idea why or what I am missing or doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about "Obout" controls, but at least for Infragistics ones the `ClientSideEvents` only contain the function **names**, not actual JavaScript code.

If I'm correct, you'd have to do something like this:

```
<cc1:ComboBox ID="ActivityTypeComboBox" runat="server" Width="100" AllowEdit="False">
    <ClientSideEvents OnSelectedIndexChanged="onActivityTypeChanged" OnItemClick="onActivityTypeClicked" />
</cc1:ComboBox>
```

Then in JS:

```
function onActivityTypeChanged()
{
    //...
}

function onActivityTypeClicked()
{
    //...
}
```

The JS functions might also get some additional parameters from the control, but you'd have to consult the documentation for that.